# How to change font color selected row column dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to change color row column 'Audiences Name'?

I want to change the text 'One, Two, Three, Four' into color blue with an underline.

How to do that? I just wanna change color 'Audiences Name' row column, not all row.

**jQuery :**

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var tabble = $('#table1').dataTable({
      "ajax": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/sk48v",
      "columns": [{
        "data": "name"
      }, {
        "data": "subtype"
      }, {
        "data": "approximate_count"
      }, {
        "data": "time_created"
      }],
      "order": [4, "desc"],
      "bStateSave": true,
      "stateSave": true,
      "bPaginate": false,
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "bFilter": false,
      "bInfo": false,
      "bAutoWidth": false
    });
  });
```

```css
table.dataTable tbody th, table.dataTable tbody td {
    color: blue;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="table1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Audience Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

> Not working on the snippet demonstration

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/jwjc76dd/2)

Comment: There is a dataTables error in the console of the JSFiddle and noe one, two, three, four... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Comment: i already update jsfiddle, you need to click 'Run'.

Comment: what happen with my fiddle? why not display when url's opened?

Comment: guys, why my row not display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `className` property in column object like this

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tabble = $('#table1').dataTable({
    "ajax": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/sk48v",
    "columns": [{
      "data": "name",
       "className": "blue"
    }, {
      "data": "subtype"
    }, {
      "data": "approximate_count"
    }, {
      "data": "time_created"
    }]
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="table1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Audience Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Date Created</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.blue {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration : underline;
}
```

Here is the working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jwjc76dd/4/)

Comment: how to make just row table with color blue, not column name.

Comment: This feature is still not allowed in JQuery datatable https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/24482/datatables-add-class-to-table-cells-but-not-table-headers#Comment_68010

Comment: this is the answer  `table.dataTable thead th:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a custom class to column and make style according to your need.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tabble = $('#table1').dataTable({
    "ajax": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/sk48v",
    "columns": [{
      "data": "name",
      "class": "custom-class" //Class here
    }, {
      "data": "subtype"
    }, {
      "data": "approximate_count"
    }, {
      "data": "time_created"
    }],
    "order": [4, "desc"],
    "bStateSave": true,
    "stateSave": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
  });
});
```

And in css

```
.custom-class {
    color: blue;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table.dataTable tbody tr.selected {
    color: white;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this, create a `class` with that CSS and once data table is loaded add that `class` to it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tabble = $('#table1').dataTable({
      "ajax": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/sk48v",
      "columns": [{
        "data": "name"
      }, {
        "data": "subtype"
      }, {
        "data": "approximate_count"
      }, {
        "data": "time_created"
      }],
      "order": [4, "desc"],
      "bStateSave": true,
      "stateSave": true,
      "bPaginate": false,
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "bFilter": false,
      "bInfo": false,
      "bAutoWidth": false
    });
});

$(document).find("#table1 thead th:first-child, #table1 td:first-child").addClass('test');
```

```css
.test {
    color: blue;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="table1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Audience Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

Comment: I have updated my code for the first field of table for `th` and `td` if you don't need for both then please remove `, #table1 td:first-child` from the code

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. You can either use inline css or use external css by specifying a classname to that row column.

I have used the inline css here.

Here's the => **[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/subhojit/41b8ujL9/1/)**

```html
<table id="table1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr> 
      <th style="color:blue; text-decoration: underline;">Audience Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Date Created</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```

```
var tabble = $('#table1').dataTable({
    "ajax": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/sk48v",
    "columns": [{
      "data": "name"
    }, {
      "data": "subtype"
    }, {
      "data": "approximate_count"
    }, {
      "data": "time_created"
    }],
    "order": [4, "desc"],
    "bStateSave": true,
    "stateSave": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<table id="table1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="color:white">Audience Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Date Created</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```